# Object.create erasing properties of object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var obj={name:'John'}
var obj1=Object.create(obj);
```

This line will add the properties on the prototype of the obj1.
so if i will use console.log(obj1.name) , as property is not existing on current object it will go up in prototype chain and get name property and its value too.

Now consider

```
var obj2={lname:'Mart'}
obj2=Object.create(obj);
```

Now it will add `name` property to its prototype which is fine.
But all properties are gone of obj2 itself. (Reason for it i can think of from crokford's shim implementation where new object is created,properties added to its prototype and then returning them)

I can do so by `obj2._ _proto_ _=obj;` (Not browser friendly for all browsers)

Now my question is if good way of `object.create` is erasing properties, how should I add properties to my prototype so that own properties of `obj2` do not get erased.

I don't want to make use of constructors. Is there any another way to add properties to prototype apart from above two. Please put light.

Comment: If you re-assign `obj2`, then you re-assign it, and the old value is gone, just like if you did `var x=1; x=2;`. `Object.create` did not "erase the property"; you did with the assignment.

Comment: If you want to see that in more detail, do `var obj2 = {lname: 'Mart'}; var obj3 = obj2; obj2 = Object.create(obj);`. Now look at `obj3` and `obj2`. `obj3` still has the `lname` property.

Comment: @Barmar obj2 does not have the lname property.please check...now point is what is good way to adding properties from the 2nd object to 1st object's prototype. and same was written there in question.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to merge objects. If you use jQuery you can use `$.extend`.

Comment: yeah that's cool but why is downvote.

Comment: Not exactly related, but notice, that when you do `obj1.name = 'new name'`, you'd create a new own property to `obj1`, that wouldn't change the value in the prorotype.

Comment: As i am talking in plain js... not jquery....moreover i am asking for ways....so why it is downvoted??

Comment: @Optimus Please re-read torazaburo's comment, the question basically doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `Object.assign`. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

#### Example

```
var obj1 = { a: "A", b: "B" };
var obj2 = { b: "XXX", c: "C" };
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
//       target ^     ^ source
console.log(obj1);
//=> { a: "A", b: "XXX", c: "C" }
//                  ^ the property from `obj2` overwrote the existing property
```

If you want to extend a prototype, just assign to the prototype instead of the object itself, e.g.:

```
Object.assign(Vector.prototype, Paths.prototype);
// Vector objects now include the methods from Paths
```

#### Compatibility

Be aware though that this is an ES2015 method. So when you deploy you will need a polyfill to support older browsers, which is provided on the MDN page:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  (function () {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var output = Object(target);
      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var source = arguments[index];
        if (source !== undefined && source !== null) {
          for (var nextKey in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(nextKey)) {
              output[nextKey] = source[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
    };
  })();
}
```